# What's the cleanest way of chaining stream functions in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

Let's say I have an array of stuff that I want to perform all sorts of wacky operations on. For example:

```
my_array = [
  { name: 'Lyra', age: 12 },
  { name: 'Harry', age: 11 },
  { name: 'Kestrel', age: 13},
]
```

I want to filter out anyone under the age of 12, change all names to symbols, and then sort them by age (say).

This can be achieved with:

```
new_array = my_array.
  select { |person| person[:age] > 11 }.
  map { |person| person.merge(name: person[:name].to_sym) }.
  sort_by { |person| person[:age] }
```

So that's all dandy. But what if I have arbitrarily complex logic I need to do my selecting/mapping/sorting/etc.?

Standard practice says that multi-line blocks with braces are to be avoided (and some linters even outright forbid it). Yet, the alternative is to start chaining `do..end` blocks, which looks even ickier:

```
new_array = my_array.
  select do |person|
    # Do something complex
  end.
  map do |person|
    # More complex stuff
  end.
  sort_by do |person|
    # Yet more complex stuff
  end
```

Does the Ruby community have any advice on best practice for chaining this sort of thing? For example, is it nicer to define a `Proc` (or similar), and pass that into the block?

Comment: _"is it nicer to define a Proc (or similar), and pass that into the block?"_ – You don't have to call the proc within the block manually, you can pass it _instead_ of a block, e.g. `filter = -> (p) { p[:age] > 11 }` and invoke it via `my_array.select(&filter)`

Comment: I find your first code chaining one-line blocks with braces perfect

Comment: @Poilon but that only works for one-liners. The question is how to deal with more complex logic, i.e. one that doesn't fit into a single line.

Comment: @Stefan yes sorry I phrased that badly - your example is what I meant. Is that a preferred pattern? It obviously makes the stream cleaner, but moves all of the logic away from the action (but I don't think that's the worst thing in the world).

Comment: Interesting question, nicely stated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a copy and use destructive methods instead:

```
new_array = my_array.dup

new_array.select! do |person|
  # Do something complex
end

new_array.map! do |person|
  # More complex stuff
end

new_array.sort_by! do |person|
  # Yet more complex stuff
end
```

Comment: Yes, certainly an option, although as a rule I try to avoid mutating objects if it can be avoided (although obviously this will depend on the exact implementation details, and so forth).

Comment: @Alec `new_array = my_array.dup` creates a copy beforehand.

Comment: Aha yes missed that.

Comment: @Alec you could also replace that with `new_array = my_array.select { ... }`, but I wanted to keep the blocks as similar as possible.

Comment: Yeah, I think a real-world solution would probably look like you suggest in your comment.

Comment: @Alec depends on your programming style I guess. I'd prefer modular code that I can easily reorder and / or comment in and out ;-)

Comment: How would you compare that with: 1) `arr = my_array.select do |person|; # Do something complex; end` then `arr == arr.map do |person|..`? Alternatively, `arr = m1(my_array); arr = m2(arr), ...` or `m3(m2(m1(my_array)))`, recognizing that in the last case you can still test `m1`, `m2` and `m3` separately.